I have an issue with my build.gradle (Flutter)
My app doesn't run anymore, pointing an error within android root build.gradle, classpath and my path,"com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.2". Specifically:

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.2:.
Required by:
project :

I've tried to integrate Firebase with my Flutter application, but when i went to build.gradle to add the classpath, there was no "dependencies" field for that, so i wrote it myself, and the issue started
This is my android\build.gradle code
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

And this is my app\build.gradle code
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.projetoelise"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.projetoelise"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


Have you tried using version 4.3.2 instead of 4.4.2?

What are the steps you followed to integrate Firebase in your Flutter application? Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

You don't need to add dependencies manually, those process are now automated.

Create a new Flutter Project
Follow the offical docs below

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android
